# Madlib on greenplum error 22003

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to test out the madlib linregr_train function on a large dataset. With certain combinations of independent variables I get the following error:

ERROR: 22003: "0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000536555291383594" is out of range for type double precision

Sometimes if I sample down the dataset these errors go away. Has anyone else experienced this problem before? Is there an option somewhere that I can set that will let me round these numbers down to zero or otherwise let me know that the result was rounded down instead of getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest possible value with doubles is approx 4.94e-324, depending on the framework / platform you are using. In your post, I count 320 zeros after the decimal point and 15 digits at the last decimal places. You are very close to the limit here. See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) for details.

Localize where the problem occurs, then try to prevent numbers which are too small.